# How to use the Select monad to solve n-queens?

Tags: haskell, monads, backtracking, n-queens

I'm trying to understand how the [`Select`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Select.html) monad works. Apparently, it is a cousin of [`Cont`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html) and it can be used for backtracking search.

I have this list-based solution to the n-queens problem:

```
-- All the ways of extracting an element from a list.
oneOf :: [Int] -> [(Int,[Int])] 
oneOf [] = [] 
oneOf (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map (\(y,ys) -> (y,x:ys)) (oneOf xs)

-- Adding a new queen at col x, is it threathened diagonally by any of the
-- existing queens?
safeDiag :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
safeDiag x xs = all (\(y,i) -> abs (x-y) /= i) (zip xs [1..])

nqueens :: Int -> [[Int]]
nqueens queenCount = go [] [1..queenCount]
  where
    -- cps = columsn of already positioned queens. 
    -- fps = columns that are still available
    go :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
    go cps [] = [cps]
    go cps fps = [ps | (p,nfps) <- oneOf fps, ps <- go (p:cps) nfps, safeDiag p cps]
```

I'm struggling to adapt this solution to use `Select` instead.

It seems that `Select` lets you abstract over the "evaluation function" that is used to compare answers. That function is passed to [`runSelect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Select.html#v:runSelect). I have the feeling that something like `safeDiag` in my solution could work as the evaluation function, but how to structure the `Select` computation itself?

Also, is it enough to use the `Select` monad alone, or do I need to use the transformer version over lists?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `Select` monad? My understanding of `Select` is that it tries to prove existence of a possible solution (as a witness proof). The typical example of `Select` is a SAT solver. You can probably force something through with `SelectT` over the list monad, but I'm more sure you would be really making use of the select monad.

Comment: @Alec I read that `Select` was good for backtracking search, and n-queens is an archetypal problem of that type, so I assumed it was a good use case for the monad.

Comment: The distinction might be between backtracking to find all solutions and backtracking until you find a solution. Then again, I've only played with `Select` once before, so don't take anything I say seriously.

Comment: Not the `Select` monad but this project : [queenslogic](https://github.com/sshastry/queenslogic) uses the `Logic` monad to solve the n-queens with backtracking.

Comment: Related: https://julesh.com/2021/03/30/selection-functions-and-lenses/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize this is question is almost 4 years old and already has an answer, but I wanted to chime in with some additional information for the sake of anyone who comes across this question in the future. Specifically, I want to try to answer 2 questions:

- how are multiple Selects that return single values combined to create a single Select that returns a sequence of values?
- is it possible to return early when a solution path is destined to fail?

#### Chaining Selects

Select is implemented as a monad transformer in the `transformers` library (go figure), but let's take a look at how one might implement `>>=` for `Select` by itself:

```hs
(>>=) :: Select r a -> (a -> Select r b) -> Select r b
Select g >>= f = Select $ \k ->
  let choose x = runSelect (f x) k
  in  choose $ g (k . choose)
```

We start by defining a new `Select` which takes an input `k` of type `a -> r` (recall that `Select` wraps a function of type `(a -> r) -> a`). You can think of `k` as a function that returns a "score" of type `r` for a given `a`, which the Select function may use to determine which `a` to return.

Inside our new `Select`, we define a function called `choose`. This function passes some `x` to the function `f`, which is the `a -> m b` portion of monadic binding: it transforms the result of the `m a` computation into a new computation `m b`. So `f` is going to take that `x` and return a new `Select`, which `choose` then runs using our scoring function `k`. You can think of `choose` as a function that asks "what would the final result be if I selected `x` and passed it downstream?"

On the second line, we return `choose $ g (k . choose)`. The function `k . choose` is the composition of `choose` and our original scoring function `k`: it takes in a value, calculates the downstream result of selecting that value, and returns the score of that downstream result. In other words, we've created a kind of "clairvoyant" scoring function: instead of returning the score of a given value, it returns the score of the final result we would get *if we selected that value*. By passing in our "clairvoyant" scoring function to `g` (the original `Select` that we're binding to), we're able to select the intermediate value that leads to the final result we're looking for. Once we have that intermediate value, we simply pass it back into `choose` and return the result.

That's how we're able to string together single-value Selects while passing in a scoring function that operates on an array of values: each Select is scoring the hypothetical final result of selecting a value, not necessarily the value itself. The applicative instance follows the same strategy, the only difference being how the downstream Select is computed (instead of passing a candidate value into the `a -> m b` function, it maps a candidate function over the 2nd Select.)

#### Returning Early

So, how can we use Select while returning early? We need some way of accessing the scoring function within the scope of the code that constructs the Select. One way to do that is to construct each Select within another Select, like so:

```hs
sequenceSelect :: Eq a => [a] -> Select Bool [a]
sequenceSelect [] = return []
sequenceSelect domain@(x:xs) = select $ \k ->
  if k [] then runSelect s k else []
  where
    s = do
      choice <- elementSelect (x:|xs)
      fmap (choice:) $ sequenceSelect (filter (/= choice) domain)
```

This allows us to test the sequence in progress and short-circuit the recursion if it fails. (We can test the sequence by calling `k []` because the scoring function includes all of the prepends that we've recursively lined up.)

Here's the whole solution:

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Select

validBoard :: [Int] -> Bool
validBoard qs = all verify (tails qs)
  where
    verify [] = True
    verify (x:xs) = and $ zipWith (\i y -> x /= y && abs (x - y) /= i) [1..] xs

nqueens :: Int -> [Int]
nqueens boardSize = runSelect (sequenceSelect [1..boardSize]) validBoard

sequenceSelect :: Eq a => [a] -> Select Bool [a]
sequenceSelect [] = return []
sequenceSelect domain@(x:xs) = select $ \k ->
  if k [] then runSelect s k else []
  where
    s = do
      choice <- elementSelect (x:|xs)
      fmap (choice:) $ sequenceSelect (filter (/= choice) domain)

elementSelect :: NonEmpty a -> Select Bool a
elementSelect domain = select $ \p -> epsilon p domain

-- like find, but will always return something
epsilon :: (a -> Bool) -> NonEmpty a -> a
epsilon _ (x:|[]) = x
epsilon p (x:|y:ys) = if p x then x else epsilon p (y:|ys)
```

In short: we construct a Select recursively, removing elements from the domain as we use them and terminating the recursion if the domain has been exhausted or if we're on the wrong track.

One other addition is the `epsilon` function (based on Hilbert's [epsilon operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus)). For a domain of size N it will check at most N - 1 items... it might not sound like a huge savings, but as you know from the above explanation, `p` will usually kick off the remainder of the entire computation, so it's best to keep predicate calls to a minimum.

The nice thing about `sequenceSelect` is how generic it is: it can be used to create any `Select Bool [a]` where

- we're searching within a finite domain of distinct elements
- we want to create a sequence that includes every element exactly once (i.e. a permutation of the domain)
- we want to test partial sequences and abandon them if they fail the predicate

Hope this helps clarify things!

---

P.S. Here's a link to an Observable notebook in which I implemented the Select monad in Javascript along with a demonstration of the n-queens solver: https://observablehq.com/@mattdiamond/the-select-monad

Comment: Nice answer. One quibble with the wording: `shift` doesn't seem to be capturing a continuation in the sense of "the rest of the computation". It just gets explicit hold of the scoring function, as you wrote.

Comment: How easy is it to make this return all solutions?

Comment: @danidiaz good point! I was actually thinking of removing `shift` anyway, as it's just a convenience function and doesn't really do that much (and the name itself is probably misleading).

Comment: @is7s That's an interesting question... I don't think there's an easy way to do it, but I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @is7s Keep in mind that Select wraps a function of type `(a -> r) -> a`... if it returned all solutions, the type would be `([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]]`, which is more like `(a -> r) -> m a`. However, it might be possible to make it work using the `SelectT` transformer, which wraps `(a -> m r) -> m a`.

Answer (score 4):

`Select` can be viewed as an abstraction of a search in a "compact" space, guided by some predicate. You mentioned SAT in your comments, have you tried modelling the problem as a SAT instance and throw it at a solver based on `Select` (in the spirit of [this paper](http://eptcs.web.cse.unsw.edu.au/paper.cgi?MSFP2014.3.pdf))? You can specialise the search to hardwire the N-queens specific constraints inside your [image: phi] and turn the SAT solver into a N-queens solver.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by jd823592's answer, and after looking at the SAT example in the [paper](http://eptcs.web.cse.unsw.edu.au/paper.cgi?MSFP2014.3.pdf), I have written this code:

```
import Data.List 
import Control.Monad.Trans.Select

validBoard :: [Int] -> Bool
validBoard qs = all verify (tails qs)
  where
    verify [] = True
    verify (x : xs) = and $ zipWith (\i y -> x /= y && abs (x-y) /= i) [1..] xs

nqueens :: Int -> [Int]
nqueens boardSize = runSelect (traverse selectColumn columns) validBoard
  where
  columns = replicate boardSize [1..boardSize]
  selectColumn candidates = select $ \s -> head $ filter s candidates ++ candidates
```

It seems to arrive (albeit slowly) to a valid solution:

```
ghci> nqueens 8
[1,5,8,6,3,7,2,4]
```

I don't understand it very well, however. In particular, the way `sequence` works for `Select`, transmuting a function (`validBoard`) that works over a whole board into functions that take a single column index, seems quite magical.

---

The `sequence`-based solution has the defect that putting a queen in a column doesn't rule out the possibility of choosing the same column for subsequent queens; we end up unnecesarily exploring doomed branches.

If we want our column choices to be affected by previous decisions, we need to go beyond `Applicative` and use the power of `Monad`:

```
nqueens :: Int -> [Int]
nqueens boardSize = fst $ runSelect (go ([],[1..boardSize])) (validBoard . fst)
  where
  go (cps,[]) = return (cps,[])
  go (cps,fps) = (select $ \s ->
    let candidates = map (\(z,zs) -> (z:cps,zs)) (oneOf fps)
    in  head $ filter s candidates ++ candidates) >>= go
```

---

The monadic version still has the problem that it only checks completed boards, when the original list-based solution backtracked as soon as a partially completed board was found to be have a conflict. I don't know how to do that using `Select`.

Comment: "In particular, the way `sequence` works for `Select` [...] seems quite magical" -- Yup, that applicative instance is positively mind-bending.